# RecyclerView has unwanted spaces on it's each of String items on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I am working with a chatting application, and it's ChatActivity that I got a problem. Please check out below images in the links:

1. **when it works fine**

[image]

2. **when it has unwanted spaces**

[image]

It's not that the spaces are in between items, but each of it's String item has unwanted space.

Since the complete code is too long, I only append below two.

**recyclerview_chat.xml (recycler view item for received chat, it's TYPE_CHAT in Adapter)**
textView17 within CardView is the textview with the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="from "
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="time "
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cardView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:maxWidth="230dp"/>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ChatAdapter.java**

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Chat> chatArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Friend> userHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Context context=null;
    private static final String TAG = "ChatAdapter";
    private String id;

    // type of layouts
    private static final int TYPE_MINE=1;
    private static final int TYPE_CHAT=2;
    private static final int TYPE_DATE=3;


    public ChatAdapter(Context context, String id, ArrayList<Chat> chatArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.chatArrayList = chatArrayList;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ChatAdapter(Context context,String id){
        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setChatArrayList(ArrayList<Chat> chatArrayList) {
        this.chatArrayList = chatArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_CHAT:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_chat,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v,viewType);
            case TYPE_MINE:
                View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_chat_my,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v1,viewType);
            case TYPE_DATE:
                View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_chat_date,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v2,viewType);
            default:
                View v3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_chat,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder(v3,viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Chat chat = chatArrayList.get(position);
        switch (holder.viewType){
            case TYPE_CHAT:
                holder.tv_body.setText(chat.getBody());
                holder.tv_date.setText(chat.getDate(Chat.TYPE_TIME));
                Friend friend;

                if (userHashMap.containsKey(chat.getFrom())){
                    friend = userHashMap.get(chat.getFrom());
                }else {
                    friend = holder.sqLite.getFriend(chat.getFrom());
                    userHashMap.put(chat.getFrom(),friend);
                }

                if (friend!=null){
                    String name = friend.getName(); // 친구이름 찾아서 넣기
                    holder.tv_from.setText(name);

                    // set blob type image on imageView
                    if (friend.isBlobSet()){
                        byte[] byteArray = friend.getImgBlob();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                        // get size of imageView
                        holder.imageView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                        int targetHeight = holder.imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                        int targetWidth = holder.imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

                        // set image
                        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, targetWidth, // FIXME: 2017. 9. 1. OutOfMemoryError
                                targetHeight, false));
                    }

                }
                break;
            case TYPE_MINE:
                holder.my_body.setText(chat.getBody());
                holder.my_date.setText(chat.getDate(Chat.TYPE_TIME));
                break;
            case TYPE_DATE:
                holder.date.setText(chat.getDate(Chat.TYPE_DATE));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (chatArrayList.get(position).isDateObject()) return TYPE_DATE;
        if (chatArrayList.get(position).getFrom().equals(id)){
            return TYPE_MINE;
        }else {
            return TYPE_CHAT;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatArrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        int viewType;

        // TYPE_CHAT
        TextView tv_from, tv_date, tv_body;
        ImageView imageView;
        MySQLite sqLite;
//        MyPreferences pref;

        // TYPE_MINE
        TextView my_date,my_body;

        // TYPE_DATE
        TextView date;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView,int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            this.viewType = viewType;

            switch (viewType){
                case TYPE_CHAT:
                    tv_from = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
                    tv_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
                    tv_body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
                    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                    sqLite = MySQLite.getInstance(context);
//                    pref = MyPreferences.getInstance(context);
                    break;
                case TYPE_MINE:
                    my_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView13);
                    my_body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView18);
                    break;
                case TYPE_DATE:
                    date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try enabling show layout bounds in developer option so you see which element is causing that space at least

Comment: try to change root layout `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`   also try remove `maxWidth` from textview

Comment: it worked with wrap_content attribute! thank you!

Comment: Since I am a newbie.. Can anybody tell me how to "close" this question somehow? or is it okay to leave it as it is now?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `trim()` function before applying it to `TextView`

```
holder.my_body.setText(chat.getBody().trim());
```

Comment: I'm afraid it can not be the solution, because the message of it's own may contain spaces

Comment: Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted. So in between space will be remained as it's

Comment: It still can not be the solution since user may want to send message with  leading or trailing spaces. Anyway I solved the issue with other help, and appreciate for your help.